# Dynamic Type checking confusion Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that takes a parameter vcType: UIViewController.Type and I'm trying to make the check

```
if getTopmostViewController() is vcType {
  // do stuff
}
```

But I'm an error "vcType is not a type". I'm not sure what the issue is or whether there is a better way to do this.

Comment: It sounds like your `vcType` parameter isn't really a type. It's an object. Do you want to check whether the topmost view controller has the same class as the `vcType` object? Or do you really want your function to take a type parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
if getTopmostViewController().isKindOfClass(vcType.dynamicType) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Above, `vcType` is an instance of some class, and it's checking whether `getTopmostViewController()` returns an instance of the same class (or a subclass).

Or maybe you really want to write a function like this:

```
func doStuffIfTopMostViewControllerHasType<VCType: UIViewController>(_: VCType.Type) {
    if getTopmostViewController() is VCType {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Which you then call like this:

```
doStuffIfTopMostViewControllerHasType(MyViewController.self)
```

Note that I'm passing the `MyViewController` class itself, **not** an instance of `MyViewController`.

Comment: AFAIU, in OP's case it will do just to check `if getTopmostViewController().isKindOfClass(vcType) { ... }` as vcType is already a meta-type.

Comment: Does anyone besides me think it's weird that the only way to get the functionality of `isKindOfClass` is thru Foundation? It wouldn't be unreasonable for Swift to have this natively.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing:

```
getTopmostViewController() is vcType
```

With:

```
getTopmostViewController().dynamicType == vcType
```

EDIT:
This would only work to check the exact type.  If the the controller returned by `getTopmostViewController()` is a descendant of vcType, then `false` would be returned.

Comment: Yes, that would work if it's only needed to check if the topmost VC is _exactly_ the `vcType`.  However, it's not going to work if it's necessary to check whether topmost VC is `vcType` _or_ one of its descendants.